# C# - Export System.Diagnostics.Tracing traces to text file

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric, system.diagnostics

I have a Service Fabric Cluster application that uses the standard EventSource for logging.

```
[EventSource(Name = "SomeName")]
internal sealed class ServiceEventSource : EventSource
{
    public static readonly ServiceEventSource Current = new ServiceEventSource();

[NonEvent]
    public void Message(string message, params object[] args)
    {
        if (this.IsEnabled())
        {
            string finalMessage = string.Format(message, args);
            Message(finalMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

My application is not yet deployed to Azure but runs in my local dev cluster. It can be deployed if that provides a solution to the following.

I have some unit test and when I run them I would like to export the traces to a text file.

I have to validate my unit test with a colleague and it will be much easier for us if we have the trace log printed on paper.

Is there anyway (hacks are fine) to do this? 
Maybe there is Azure service I can hook into and get the data from there?

Copy paste from the diagnostic viewer in Visual Studio 2019 can only be done 1 line at a time. I have hundreds.

Any ideas?

Comment: What about `TextWriterTraceListener`? As it described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/how-to-create-and-initialize-trace-listeners) Not sure, that it's applicable for Azure Service Fabric

Comment: you need a ETW listener to capture ETW events